# iText PDF fails with message "Dictionary key endstream is not a name"

Tags: pdf, itext, pdf-generation

The issue is the same as reported [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23889939/267197).

I have taken [this image](https://dl.dropbox.com/s/37wudw0da7xbpss/itext_banner_InvalidPdfException.jpg) and converted to [this PDF](https://dl.dropbox.com/s/xz77curzkigod0k/itext_banner_InvalidPdfException.pdf) using GraphicsMagick v1.3.26 (build on 2017-07-04):

`gm convert itext_banner_InvalidPdfException.jpg itext_banner_InvalidPdfException.pdf`

When I try to read it with iText v5.5.12 I get the following exception:

```
java -cp itextpdf-5.5.12.jar com.itextpdf.text.pdf.parser.PdfContentReaderTool itext_banner_InvalidPdfException.pdf
com.itextpdf.text.exceptions.InvalidPdfException: Rebuild failed: Dictionary key endstream is not a name. at file pointer 1197; Original message: Dictionary key endstream is not a name. at file pointer 1197
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader.readPdf(PdfReader.java:764)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader.<init>(PdfReader.java:197)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader.<init>(PdfReader.java:235)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader.<init>(PdfReader.java:223)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader.<init>(PdfReader.java:213)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.parser.PdfContentReaderTool.listContentStream(PdfContentReaderTool.java:200)
    at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.parser.PdfContentReaderTool.main(PdfContentReaderTool.java:249)
```

Questions:

- What exactly is wrong with given PDF? It seems like there is an issue in GhostScript which is used indirectly by GraphicsMagick.
- When I open it with [iText RUPS v5.8.8](https://netcologne.dl.sourceforge.net/project/itextrups/5.5.8/itext-rups-5.5.8-jar-with-dependencies.jar), it does not print any warnings to *Console* tab. Does it mean it is valid from iText RUPS point of view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your PDF contains this broken object:

```
11 0 obj
<<

endstream
endobj
```

The opening `<<` is closed by a `endstream`. This does not match.

If that object was meant to be a mere dictionary, it should have looked like this:

```
11 0 obj
<<
    [a reasonable number of dictionary entries]
>>
endobj
```

If that object was meant to be a stream, it should have looked like this:

```
11 0 obj
<<
    [a reasonable number of dictionary entries]
>>
stream
    [stream data]
endstream
endobj
```

---

BTW, the object in question is not referenced from any other object in the PDF. If you open the PDF in a `PdfReader` in partial mode, therefore, the issue will be ignored.

Comment: Do you happen to know why iText RUPS does not report it? I think it was designed also for that matter: to recover broken structure but to report it as well.

Comment: I'll have a look later. But I wouldn't expect RUPS to handle this error specifically.